# Autoconf -- save program output in variable

Tags: autotools, configure, autoconf

I have an autoconf problem. During .`/configure`, I need to compile and run a small C program, and capture and prune it's stdout into a variable and then confirm the variable was successfully set. It feels like this should be simple, but I've been struggling for several hours.

I am hoping to parse the stdout:

```
hello "world"
```

And store the contents of the quoted string in the variable GREETING. Instead
my snippet generates the error "Cannot detect greeting".

Here's what I have so far:

```
AC_RUN_IFELSE(
        [AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
            [[#include <stdio>]],
            [[printf("hello \"world\"\n");]])
        ],
        [AC_SUBST(GREETING,
            [[`./conftest$EXEEXT | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'`]])
        ]
    )
if test -z "${GREETING}"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot detect greeting])
fi
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are over-quoting many of your macro arguments, and under-quoting another.  In any case, for testing purposes, at least, I suggest adding code that verifies more directly which branch of the `AC_RUN_IF_ELSE` is taken.  You could use an `AC_MSG_NOTICE` for this, or an `AC_MSG_CHECKING` / `AC_MSG_RESULT` pair.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using `autoconf 2.69` and I implemented a cached test with `AC_RUN_IFELSE` that #defines a MACRO to be used by my program. This goes through an environment variable, so it is useful if you only need that too.

A problem that I found with `AC_RUN_IFELSE` is that it does not write to a file (as is suggested by an example in the documentation); it seems only intended to test if a program compiles, links AND runs (that is, has exit code 0).

If you are confident that your program will run when it compiles and links, you might as well use `AC_LINK_IFELSE`, which also produces a binary - but doesn't test if that returns exit code 0.

Doing caching, using `AC_CACHE_CHECK`, the test program is only compiled, linked and run when that wasn't done before; but the result is still printed (aka:

> checking for greeting message... world (cached)

Where 'world' is the cached value. In other words, this prints the cached value. However `AC_RUN_IFELSE` *also* prints the program output to `stdout`! So, if the value wasn't cached yet this would produce the output twice. As in

> checking for greeting message... world
> world

The solution to this seems to print your output to `stderr`, which is sent to the log file rather than the screen.

A complete autoconf macro then becomes something like,

```
AC_DEFUN([CW_SYS_GREETING],
[AC_CACHE_CHECK(
    [for greeting message],
    [cw_cv_system_greeting],[dnl
    AC_LANG_PUSH(C)
    AC_RUN_IFELSE([dnl
        AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
            [#include <stdio.h>],
            [fprintf(stderr, "hello \"world\"\n")])],
        [cw_cv_system_greeting=$(./conftest$EXEEXT 2>&1 | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/')],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR(Failed to compile a test program!?)])
    AC_LANG_POP(C)])
eval "CW_GREETING=$cw_cv_system_greeting"
AC_SUBST(CW_GREETING)
m4_pattern_allow(CW_GREETING)
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([CW_GREETING], $cw_cv_system_greeting, [The greeting to use.])
])
```

Which would add

```
/* The greeting to use. */
#define CW_GREETING world
```

to `config.h`.

**NOTE** that I use the prefix `CW_` for my macros in order not to collide with ones defined by autoconf. To make sure everything is expanded, I therefore also add to my configure.ac:

```
dnl Detect unexpanded macros.
m4_pattern_forbid([^AX_]) dnl These macros are defined in the package 'autoconf-archive' available from the ubuntu "universe" repository.
m4_pattern_forbid([^CW_])
m4_pattern_forbid([^LT_])
```

This is why I also need/added the `m4_pattern_allow(CW_GREETING)` because this C macro isn't expanded by m4, but uses the same prefix.